# WPF setting popup background to match theme

Tags: wpf, popup, themes

So, I'm using a popup control to display a message.  It works fine and the code is below:

```
      <Popup x:Name="popup" Width="300" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=DetailsTextBox}" Placement="Top" StaysOpen="true" AllowsTransparency="False" PopupAnimation="Slide">
           <Grid>
               <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">Message Contents...</TextBlock>
           </Grid>
      </Popup>
```

The problem I'm having it that no matter what the theme is, the background is black.  That's fine for some themes, but themes like Bureau Black or Bureau Blue give me blue text that isn't all that readable.  While I could just set the text to be white and be done with it, I would like it to match the theme.  So, how can I set the background color to match the theme?

BTW, some threads had suggested setting AllowsTransparency to True, but that just makes the background transparent and it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: so what `Background` do you want the `Popup` to have? If you want it's Background to be the same as the `Window`, give the `Window` a name like `x:Name="window"` and in the `Grid` within `Popup`, Bind to it, `<Grid Background="{Binding ElementName=window, Path=Background}">`?

Comment: If you are using the themes in the WPF Toolkit they have standard resources. So for instance you can set the background to {DynamicResource ControlBackgroundBrush}, and when you use the various themes the resource will resolve to the brush used in the specific theme. You may prefer another brush such as WindowBackgroundBrush, or something else, but all the popups in those themes seem to use ControlBackgroundBrush.